# Moving an object in Active Directory with c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

so the following code is supposed to move an object in active directory.  I see what is going on here but i dont quite understand it.  all i see is the old location and new location.  I dont see how I actually grab the object.  I have several objects in both locations, where does this code say what specific object is to be moved?  I dont see where in the LDAP + objectLocation string that there is an object.

```
DirectoryEntry eLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + objectLocation);
DirectoryEntry nLocation = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + newLocation);
string newName = eLocation.Name;
eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation, newName);
nLocation.Close();
eLocation.Close();
```

Comment: `MoveTo` does the actual moving of an object pointed to by the `eLocation` to the location specified by `nLocation`. I don't quite get your question but the code seems legit.

Comment: The object you're moving is specified by `eLocation`, you're moving it to the location specified by `nLocation`, and the second `MoveTo` overload allows you to rename the object you're moving.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe this example will make it clearer:

```
DirectoryEntry theObjectToMove = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=jdoe,CN=Users,DC=acme,DC=com");
DirectoryEntry theNewParent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Something,DC=acme,DC=com");
theObjectToMove.MoveTo(theNewParent);
```

The overload of `MoveTo` with two parameters also specifies a new name for the object, and I think that in your example it's redundant.